# How to set text into Summernote textarea with Capybara + Poltergeist

Tags: rspec, capybara, poltergeist, summernote

I have a textarea which is using [Summernote](http://summernote.org) and I set onChange event to it. I want to write test with RSpec + Capybara + Poltergeist to confirm the onChange event is working.

As far as I checked, the textarea displayed in browser is actually div tag with 'note-editable' css class. How can I set text to it and fire onChange event?

I wrote a code like this, but got an error `Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find field "Some label"`:

```
visit edit_foo_path
fill_in 'Some label', with: 'Foo bar'
```

### EDIT

I created a sample app for this issue:

https://github.com/JunichiIto/summernote-rspec-sandbox

#### Raw HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>SummernoteRspecSandbox</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application.self-f866ffa01bf26be2b8a8ac982e49d917be3b9a46604dfdc9fc8c139b62409465.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
  <script src="/assets/jquery.self-d03a5518f45df77341bdbe6201ba3bfa547ebba8ed64f0ea56bfa5f96ea7c074.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.self-ca5248a2fad13d6bd58ea121318d642f195f0b2dd818b30615f785ff365e8d1f.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.self-2bbd2c0465f01b1f8270958ddfc2e62a08915f295a35d22df2971eb936cf3c64.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/summernote.self-612431947ae9c3f1f0283dbbbc757153947f8e5de408f9bd8886b1232e8a54f7.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/blogs.self-b9a3bc0ee16e0bc44fb466bd5c7833ebec276447634d25729280397c65cff176.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.self-f8806224e027f3e3f0138ea9ce99319e298dfdb323304d1f1be6eae8e8c74724.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="4iu31ugTgvMERb1xQRjtcySSssjMthLWclgiHMe60aHGMeC3IMeNKZlkfFSKT33hNuvDqUUgUNTUaQEcoBl9mw==" />
</head>
<body>

<h1>New Blog</h1>

<form class="new_blog" id="new_blog" action="/blogs" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="TBkcVk38/42Cx9coe717KKpb1H2cmDpv8kz7LREfkiloA0s3hSjwVx/mFg2w6uu6uCKlHBUOeG1Ufdgtdrw+Ew==" />

  <div class="field">
    <label for="blog_title">Title</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="blog[title]" id="blog_title" />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="blog_content">Content</label><br>
    <textarea class="summernote" name="blog[content]" id="blog_content">
</textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Create Blog" />
  </div>
</form>

<a href="/blogs">Back</a>


</body>
</html>
```

#### CoffeeScript

```
$ ->
  $('.summernote').summernote()
```

#### RSpec

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature 'Blogs' do
  scenario 'Create blog' do
    visit new_blog_path
    fill_in 'Title', with: 'Hello, world!'
    fill_in 'Content', with: 'This is awesome blog.'
    click_button 'Create Blog'
    expect(page).to have_content 'Blog was successfully created.'
    expect(page).to have_content 'Hello, world!'
    expect(page).to have_content 'This is awesome blog.'
  end

  scenario 'Create blog with JS', js: true do
    visit new_blog_path
    fill_in 'Title', with: 'Hello, world!'
    pending 'Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find field "Content"'
    fill_in 'Content', with: 'This is awesome blog.'
    click_button 'Create Blog'
    expect(page).to have_content 'Blog was successfully created.'
    expect(page).to have_content 'Hello, world!'
    expect(page).to have_content 'This is awesome blog.'
  end
end
```

Comment: can you show us the full html please?

Comment: I added the detailed information. If you need more, please let me know.

Comment: well I primarily use ids and classes as locators but you can use name in a lot of instances, in your case try `fill_in 'blog[content]' with: text here` or `fill_in '#blog_content' with: text here`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capybaras fill_in only works with html form elements. Since the JS version of your page is using a DIV with the contenteditable attribute as its text area to be filled #fill_in will not work.  Instead you need to find the div and call #set on it directly.  In your project the following should work

```
find('div[contenteditable]').set('This is awesome blog.')
```

Answer (score 4):

After updating Summernote to 0.8.2, `find('div[contenteditable]').set('This is awesome blog.')` does not work.

I had to call Summernote API via `execute_script` like:

```
script = <<-JS
$('.some-field').summernote('editor.insertText', 'This is awesome blog.');
JS
execute_script(script)
```

### EDIT

> After updating Summernote to 0.8.2, `find('div[contenteditable]').set('This is awesome blog.')` does not work.

Sorry, this was not what I wanted to say. I should have said like this:

After updating Summernote to 0.8.2, `find('div[contenteditable]').set('This is awesome blog.')` does not fire Summernotes's onChange callback. So I had to call `execute_script`.

I have to test onChange behavior in my specs.

### EDIT 2

As Thomas Walpole wrote, `send_keys` method could be used instead of `execute_script`. Thanks Thomas Walpole!

```
find('div[contenteditable]').send_keys('This is awesome blog.')
```

Comment: Dropping to JS to set values when testing should be the absolute last option since it completely bypasses the events a user would generate when using your app and makes your tests mostly meaningless.  There is nothing in Summernote 0.8.2 that should change how this behaves - here is a gist showing it still working with Poltergeist  https://gist.github.com/twalpole/b43ed98f458cea47ce3c230cf6e638e7 - so I'm assuming something else changed in your app to break your test.

Comment: You are correct. As I edited, I had to call `execute_script` to fire onChange callback in my specs.

Comment: This is because Poltergeist doesn't use send_keys when setting an elements value (might be changing soon).  To get what you want without executing JS do something like  `find('div[contenteditable]').send_keys([:ctrl, 'a'], 'This is awesome blog.')`  You might need to do a `find('div[contenteditable]').click` first - but that should trigger the change event.  (Note: you might need to swap  :ctrl for :meta or :alt depending on the platform you're on - or not need the [:ctrl, 'a'] at all if there wasn't any previous content you need to replace)