# Capybara: Set value of summernote textarea

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, summernote

I'm trying to test a implementation of summernote `0.8.1.0` in my Rails app.

I realized that `fill_in` won't work because `fill_in` only works with html form elements and summernote is using a DIV with the `contenteditable` attribute.

I found a solution from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30921215/1713912, but it doesn't work for me.

Any ideas for a solution is much appreciated!

My test:

```
it "allows admins to add text blocks to events", js: true, focus: true do
    click_on "Add text block"
    expect(page).to have_content "Text block content"
    all("div[contenteditable]").last.set("Dummy text")
    click_on "Publish now"
    expect(page).to have_content "Event created successfully"
    expect(Event.last.text_blocks.last.text_attachment.content).to eq "Dummy text"
end
```

### Update: Added test log

```
1) events feature event creation adding content blocks allows admins to add text blocks to events
     Failure/Error: expect(Event.last.text_blocks.last.text_attachment.content).to eq "Dummy text"

       expected: "Dummy text"
            got: ""

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/features/event_feature_spec.rb:76:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What error do you get? And what driver are you using?

Comment: @TomWalpole See updated question. I'm using webkit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set text into Summernote textarea with Capybara + Poltergeist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30836587/how-to-set-text-into-summernote-textarea-with-capybara-poltergeist)

Comment: Please see my own answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30836587/how-to-set-text-into-summernote-textarea-with-capybara-poltergeist